# Typescript - Any of all interface keys as a type

Tags: typescript, object, types, interface, key

[image: code]

What should be the type of `name` so that the function `getValue` only allows for one of `Data` key types as it argument.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `keyof Data` for the `name` argument? You can do it like

```
const getValue = (name: keyof Data) => data[name];
```